# gbm with caret when tuning grid has n.trees

Tags: r, caret, boosting

While using `caret` package to tune a `gbm` model, suppose the tuning grid has `n.trees=c(100,200)`. After constructing 100 trees and evaluating the performance metrics, does `caret` package

(i) discard all those trees and construct new 200 trees? OR

(ii) construct only 100 more trees?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save time, `caret` will build a model on 200 trees, and evaluate the model use 100 and 200 trees.

This is because the nature of the gradient boosting model, that the model can be evaluated by using first n trees. See [gbm doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) predict function.

Answer (score 0):

It starts from tree No 1 again- the way boosting framework works is a bit different than building normal trees.. in fact it built trees on the error of the previously built tree.

Comment: You say "it built trees on the error of the previously built tree". So why not use the previously built 100 trees and build new 100 trees to explain the residuals from the first 100 trees. Why discard the initial 100?

Comment: It starts again, trees are depended on the previous ones, in grid you have more changing parameters (four tuning parameters for gbm), so to do it parallel you create for different parameter value sets all demanded trees once again (on a different core). Just use:registerDoParallel(4);
getDoParWorkers()